# dropDuplicates with non-numeric condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this (I have a few more columns, but they aren't relevant):

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+                                        
|item_id    |location_id|decision       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|     111111|  A        |        True   |
|     111111|  A        |        False  |
|     111111|  A        |        False  |
|     222222|  B        |        False  |
|     222222|  B        |        False  |
|     333333|  C        |        True   |
|     333333|  C        |        True   |
|     333333|  C        |        Unsure |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

I would like to do `dropDuplicates("item_id", "location_id")` so I can remove rows that have the same `item_id` and `location_id`, but I want to keep a row that contains `True`OR `Unsure` if it exists. If none of the duplicate rows contain `True` or `Unsure`, any row with `False` is fine. For the above example, I would like the resulting dataframe to look like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+                                        
|item_id    |location_id|decision       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|     111111|  A        |        True   |
|     222222|  B        |        False  |
|     333333|  C        |        Unsure |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

For `item_id` 111111 and `location_id` A, I want the row with `decision` True since one such row exists. For `item_id` 222222 and `location_id` B, since none of the rows contain True, selecting either is fine. For `item_id` 333333 and `location_id` C, all rows contain the desired values of either `True` or `Unsure`, so selecting any one of the three is fine.

I am using Scala, so solution in Scala would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for that:

### Input Preparation:

```scala
//spark : My SparkSession
import spark.implicits._
  val df = Seq(
    (111111, "A", "True"),
    (111111, "A", "False"),
    (111111, "A", "False"),
    (222222, "B", "False"),
    (222222, "B", "False"),
    (333333, "C", "True"),
    (333333, "C", "True"),
    (333333, "C", "Unsure")
  ).toDF("item_id", "location_id", "decision")

  df.printSchema()
  /** root
    * |-- item_id: integer (nullable = false)
    * |-- location_id: string (nullable = true)
    * |-- decision: string (nullable = true)
    */
```

### Code for achieving the desired output:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

//Step 1) create a WindowSpec : MyWindow is same as that of groupBy("item_id", "location_id") 
//but I want to keep track of the order of True, False and Unsure in that partition 
//so, will order my partition based on the col("decision") which is why we have window functions.
  val MyWindow = Window
    .partitionBy(col("item_id"), col("location_id"))
    .orderBy(desc("decision"))

  df
//Step 2) add row_number to each record in that window (based on the mentioned ordering in MyWindow),
//in this case based on the descending order of col("decision")
    .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(MyWindow))
//Step 3) It turns out we only need first row from each partition  
//based on the decision to select Unsure (then) True (then) False (based on the order of preference),
//so, we filter in only first row.
    .filter(col("row_number").equalTo(1))
    .drop(col("row_number"))
    .orderBy(col("item_id"))
    .show(false)


/**
OUTPUT:
+-------+-----------+--------+
|item_id|location_id|decision|
+-------+-----------+--------+
|111111 |A          |True    |
|222222 |B          |False   |
|333333 |C          |Unsure  |
+-------+-----------+--------+
*/
```

---

### EDIT1 (as per comments):

Improved Code (without ordering col("decision") in WindowSpec):

For achieving this, you need to write Custom [UserDefinedAggregateFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction) for you to have more control over decision attribute range of values, in your requirement it can be like this:

```scala
 object MyBestDecisionUDF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

    // step 1) : to set priority score to your decisions which you can configure somewhere
    val decisionOrderMap =
      Map("Unsure" -> 4, "True" -> 3, "False" -> 2, "Zinc" -> 1, "Copper" -> 0)

    /** all overridden functions come from UserDefinedAggregateFunction Abstract Class
      */
    override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(
      StructField("input_str", StringType, false) :: Nil
    )

    override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(
      StructField("buffer_str", StringType, false) :: Nil
    )

    override def dataType: DataType = StringType

    override def deterministic: Boolean = true

    override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
      buffer.update(0, "")
    }

    override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
      // main step : updating buffer always to hold best decision string value
      if (
        decisionOrderMap.getOrElse(
          buffer.get(0).toString(),
          -1
        ) < decisionOrderMap.getOrElse(input(0).toString(), -1)
      ) {
        buffer.update(0, input(0))
      }

    }

    override def merge(
        buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer,
        buffer2: Row
    ): Unit = {}

    override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
      buffer(0)
    }

  }

  /** ############################################################### 
    * Calling Custom UDAF
    * ###############################################################
    */

/**
INPUT:

+-------+-----------+--------+
|item_id|location_id|decision|
+-------+-----------+--------+
|111111 |A          |True    |
|111111 |A          |False   |
|111111 |A          |False   |
|222222 |B          |False   |
|222222 |B          |False   |
|333333 |C          |True    |
|333333 |C          |Unsure  |
|444444 |D          |Copper  |
|444444 |D          |Zinc    |
+-------+-----------+--------+

*/

  df
  // Custom UDF evaluated column
    .withColumn(
      "my_best_decision",
      MyBestDecisionUDF(col("decision")).over(
        Window
          .partitionBy(col("item_id"), col("location_id"))
      )
    )
    .drop(col("decision"))
    .distinct()
    .orderBy(col("item_id"))
    .show(false)
/**
 * OUTPUT:
+-------+-----------+----------------+
|item_id|location_id|my_best_decision|
+-------+-----------+----------------+
|111111 |A          |True            |
|222222 |B          |False           |
|333333 |C          |Unsure          |
|444444 |D          |Zinc            |
+-------+-----------+----------------+
*/
```

Comment: Let's say there are more possible values that can occur in the `decision` column (let's say something that starts with letter Z). How would I modify the code? it seems like `.orderBy(desc("decision"))` relies on the fact that U > T > F when sorting the strings

Comment: I ended up appending literals (1, 2, etc) to the `decision` column and sorting using `asc`. This is to help with the problem mentioned in my comment above. Appending literals allows to me to explicitly define which values of `decision` I want to prioritize.

Comment: @sam Sure, that is one more way you can do and using user defined aggregate functions (referring to my EDIT 1) you can do it in another way to have more control over your logic of prioritising on things.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of your comment on Lingaraj's answer, there's a slightly more sophisticated way of solving it than adding literals to the `decision`. You can instead create a boolean:

`val decisionIsImportant = col("decision") === "True" || col("decision") === "Unsure" || col("decision") === Zebra || col("decision") == Xylophone`

This boolean will evaluate to `True` if the `decision` column is equal to any of the values you want to prioritize.

Then, you can create a Window and apply it to the DataFrame:

```
val decisionSortWindow = Window
      .partitionBy(col("item_id"), col("location_id")))
      .orderBy(decisionIsImportant.desc)

df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(MyWindow))
  .filter(col("row_number").equalTo(1))
  .drop(col("row_number"))
  .orderBy(col("item_id"))
  .show(false)
```

Since all the `decision` values that evaluate to `True` will be sorted first, you can just filter by `col("row_number").equalTo(1)`, since row number 1 is guaranteed to be one of the important decisions if one is present.